# Add github repository where I am a collaborator?

Tags: support, jobs

I am shaping up my Careers resumé, but I have one problem which I am unable to solve.

I initially [forked](https://github.com/rbrito/coursera-1) a repository on github (for downloading videos from the MOOC platform Coursera) and soon after I started sending pull requests [upstream](https://github.com/jplehmann/coursera).

Eventually, the original author thought that my contributions were, in his words, of consistent high quality and trusted, he made me a repo collaborator, giving me write access.

Since the original project earned a lot of momentum (has a reasonable following (almost 600) and forks (almost 150), and because I only care about the original project, and not my fork, I would like my resumé to reflect the reality and have that repository in my list of projects of github projects.

Unfortunately, asking Careers to import my profile from github only imports my fork, not the real project.

I tried to fix this situation by inserting manually the URL of the repository where I am a collaborator, but as it is located in github, Careers 2.0 tells me that I should use the specialized method for github.

What should I do to fix that situation?

P.S.: As far as I could read the existing questions (while "doing my homework"), none of them deals exactly with the issue that I'm having.